# Memory efficient way of creating a large PostGIS table

Tags: raster, postgis, sql, memory

I am trying to add the results of a query to PostGIS DB. My query converts a raster band into polygons. Although the original raster is quite big (~150GB, 12 bands) my below query runs reasonably fast (~30min).

```
SELECT
    (gv).x,
    (gv).y,
    (gv).val,
    ST_AsText((gv).geom)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast,
        1) AS gv
    FROM
        myschema.myraster) foo;
```

However, when I add `CREATE TABLE` to the above query (see below) it runs forever and I get an error message

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.newtable AS
SELECT
    (gv).x,
    (gv).y,
    (gv).val,
    ST_AsText((gv).geom)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast,
        1) AS gv
    FROM
        myschema.myraster) foo;
    

SQL Error [53100]: ERROR: could not extend file "base/16405/280404923.657": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 86186975
  Hint: Check free disk space.
```

I read some articles that say it's due to the temporary tables that are generated during the process. Do I need these tables? If not, how can I modify my SQL script to avoid these tables being generated?
Or if this is not an issue - can my SQL code be improved to overcome this issue?

Comment: or you could move your tablespaces to a larger disk

Comment: Do you mean increasing the size of my database? I thought this issue is memory-related and not storage-related?

Comment: The error says check free diskspace, your disk is full

Comment: Raster storage is space efficient because the coordinates are implicit. Converting a 150GiB raster to vector could easily use a score of terabytes, possibly hundreds. If you don't have at least a few TiB free, there's little chance of success here.

Comment: Thank you. I am only interested in the footprint of the raster - not the values.  I just realized using `ST_DumpAsPolygons` will be a better choice for me. Do you think this will significantly reduce the size? Also, I am only converting one band (150gb/12) not the entire raster.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am trying to compare and create measures of fit between this raster footprint (i.e raster value != NA) and a multi-polygon database table. I thought converting this to a polygon database table will make things easier. So this was the first step.

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Envelope.html will give you your footprint extents.